# What would be an optimal number for "maximum instance count" for Elastic BeanStalk's auto scale configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

Can I give 10/100/1000/10000?
What is the maximum number, that is optimal?
What is the maximum number that someone had tried?

Also How do I add other zones into "Custom Availability zones"?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkFST.png

Answer (score 2):

> Also How do I add other zones into "Custom Availability zones"?

You can't. AWS will show only those availability zones that it can launch you EC2 instances into.

> Can I give 10/100/1000/10000? What is the maximum number, that is
>   optimal? What is the maximum number that someone had tried?

There is no one-size-fits-all "optimal" number. It totally depends on your app (and instance type).

You will not be able to scale to 1000 instances anyway. The maximum number of instances you can launch in a region is displayed in "EC2" -> "Limits" section of AWS Console. You can request an increase of this limit, but I doubt AWS support will allow you to run 10000 instances without proper justification.

Comment: You can't. AWS will show only those availability zones that it can launch you EC2 instances into. - If I create a fresh BeanStalk env or EC2 instance in each zone, can I see all zones in Custom Availability zones?

Comment: That usually depends on 1) You instance type. Sometimes AWS is short of capacity for certain instance types in a given AZ. 2) Which zones you chose for your load balancer(s).